# Empty string as Null in Access but not in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am in in process of upsizing an existing application written in classic asp with Access database as backend to SQL server as backend. The code enters empty strings ('' - two ticks) when the user leaves a blank cell and when the data is displayed back, Access version treats this ticks as Null, where as the SQl version does not. Ex: There is a 4 column entry form, the first is text and then there are three  4 digit time fields. These time fields are of type Text in Access where as they are varchar in SQL server. When the data is displayed, Access displays only the first text & ignores the empty strings (values with ticks) where as SQl server version attempts to display time values with spaces. It is fine when these time fields are really having values bit not when left balnk. The code also has color code - only text as blue but with times, it diaplays it in red. Trying to find a simple solution without changing the code. An empty string (with two consecutive single quotes) is a value for SQL server where as Null for Access. Bottom line question is: How do I make SQL server also interpret empty string as Null without changing code?..I tested ANSI NULL settings to on or off - but did not help..Any database wide settings?! Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Comment: I have found a solution. The deafult value of '' (empty string with two single quotes) which were not quite exactly defined in SQL server. I had (N' ') instead of ("") as default value. Once I made the correction, everything started working just fine! I was aware of NULLIF as well as ISNULL functions but did not wanted to change the code, as such number of other functions does not exists identically as they are in access, e.g. instr, iff, CDate are just a few examples which does not exist in SQL server which I had to change. Thanks also for INSTEAD OF trigger idea which I could use in future!

Answer (score 0):

A very short function for SQL to see an empty string as NULL is `NULLIF(myColumn, '')`. This will 'return' null if the string is empty. How you implement this is up to you. When you say 'without changing code', that may or may not be possible. But for example, you could use computed columns so that you are not changing asp code, but it requires a schema change to the database. Or you could use that function by modifying your query against the existing columns...would such a modification really be impossible for your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement 'INSTEAD OF' triggers on the tables in SQL Server converting all empty strings to null, using the previously mentioned NULLIF function.
If you are not familiar with this type of trigger, here is a link [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)